# Проект загружает процессор

Tags: asp.net-core, google-cloud

Помогите разобраться в чем проблема.

Начал пробовать ASP.NET Core и решил попробовать его на Google Cloud.
В VS 20017 установил Cloud Tools и создал дефолтный ASP.NET Core Web Application. Проверил на локальном компьютере - все нормально работает.

Выкатил его через Publish to Google Cloud на App Engine Flex. Но через некоторое время в мониторинге заметил постоянную загрузку процессора на сервере, порядка 5%.

В чем проблема? Может что то не так делаю?
Пробовал "Hello World" на PHP и Python, там нет такой утечки.